# How to use math operators with strings?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, operators

I need to display a certain number on a label when the user input is between >=0 and <= 1. User input is a string and I need the numbers between to be a decimal or double. Obviously I can't compare the two like I did because the operators can't compare a string and decimal, double, or int.

```
private void voltageTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var RTPower = powerTextBox.Text;
    powerTextBox.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;

    if (RTPower >= 0 && <= 1)
    {
        displayLabel4.Text = "1";
    }
}
```

> Error: Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'
>
> Error: Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'

How can I make that if statement work? Do I have to keep it as a string, display it in label, convert the label to an integer then re-display it? I know I can make that work, but that is far too complicated. I just need an easier way to do this.

Comment: Yes, you need to convert it to an integer in order to do operations on it.

Comment: If you don't want to do all that "work", use a **NumericUpDown** and set appropriate Minimum/Maximum values.

Comment: you could use `double.TryParse`.

Comment: and you have an error in `&& <= 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int RTPower = Int32.Parse(powerTextBox.Text);
```

or for decimal values

```
decimal RTPower = Decimal.Parse(powerTextBox.Text);
```

You need to convert the value from a string to an int.

Also, I assume you are new to c# - my advice would be to avoid using var and explicitly declare your variables.  It will make things clear and easier for you to learn and understand.

Comment: I need it to compare to decimal though and read 0. The first answer you gave me doesn't work when I start inputing values like 0.1, .72, 0.59

Comment: updated the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to int like

```
int x = Int32.Parse(RTPower);
```

then you can compare x.

---

If, however, you know that the user input will be between [0, 9] then you could use

```
if(RTPower >= "0" && <= "1")
```

because strings are compared lexicographically so "1" is under "9" but "10" is under "2".

**The first way is much better though, because it works for all numerical user inputs**

Comment: I need it to compare to decimal though and read 0. The first answer you gave me doesn't work when I start inputing values like 0.1, .72, 0.59